# Почему пользователи интернета всё чаще забывают ставить мягкий знак в глаголах, или наоборот ставят не там, где нужно? Это не про ТЬСЯ/ТСЯ

Tags: глаголы, мягкий-знак

Я часто в последнее время вижу, что пользователи интернета всё чаще допускают ошибку при написании глагола с мягким знаком на конце: нередко забывают ставить Ь на конце таких глаголов, или наоборот, ставят Ь не там, где это нужно. Про ТЬСЯ/ТСЯ здесь вообще промолчу, так как об этой ошибке в написании возвратных глаголов уже много написано в интернете и до сих пор не перестаёт вызывать затруднения у носителей русского языка.

Comment: Какие уж там затруднения. Любой, самый безграмотный человек способен определить на какой вопрос отвечает возвратный глагол: "что делать" (ться) или "что делает" (тся). А неправильно пишут из-за того, что фигачат на автомате. Я сам постоянно так ошибаюсь, хотя на безграмотность не жалуюсь)

Comment: @user190920
  А вы не пробовали грамотно фигачить на  автомате?  Ну, к примеру, такие предложения: Учиться всегда пригодится. Не годится ей молодиться. А эту поговорку я для вас придумала (для тренировки  автоматического письма): Что не повторится, тому и забыться.  Может, и с другими своей методикой поделитесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **У мягкого знака в русском языке три функции:** (1) обозначение мягкости звука, (2) обозначение грамматических форм (2-е лицо ед. число, повелительное наклонение); (3) разделительный знак между согласным и гласным звуком. В каждой теме действуют свои правила.

Изменить эти правила невозможно, они определяются объективными законами русского письма. Поэтому пользователям Интернета  придется или разобраться с правилами, или **вовсе не писать по-русски**, если грамотное письмо для них важно и престижно.

Надо сказать, что в **последнее время** стали хуже учить и менее старательно учиться — в наш стремительный век на все не хватает времени.

2. Что касается **ТЬСЯ/ТСЯ**, то там еще сложнее. Проверка *что делаТЬ/что делаЕТ* подходит для простейших грамматических структур, а ведь инфинитив может быть любым членом предложения. Будем делать грамматический разбор? Это сложно!

**А причину этой орфограммы** многие ли знают? Это частица СЯ (ТСЯ и ТЬСЯ читаются одинаково, как ЦА). Можно убрать СЯ из предложения, не делая разбора, и тогда все с мягким знаком будет ясно, например: *Ни слова не сказала я, за что ж ему сердиТЬ(СЯ)?* (ТЬ без СЯ пишется по слуху).

Кто нашим пользователям все это объяснит! Поэтому к концу десятого года обучения такие темы усваиваются интуитивно. А если не к концу десятого, то вообще не усваиваются. А ведь это вещи довольно простые, не высшая математика.